# Which removal tool do I need for this 16t bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

The bottom bracket that you see in the picture has a strange 16 teeth profile (3-1-3-1-...). 
I had this bike built a few years ago and I don't remember what model the BB is. I wonder what removal tool I can buy to remove and replace this BB.

I will list other components around the BB, which may help to identify the model:

- track Miche Primato Advanced crankset (JIS)
- Mash Work frame with BSA BB threading

[image: bottom bracket picture]

**Edit**: After dismounting the BB, I have its manufacturer/model information: VP Components VP-BC73.

Comment: I'd guess the other side is the same, once you get the crank off with a square-taper crank puller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a typical 20 tooth (Park Tool BBT-22/32) tool should do the job. I'm not sure why every 5th spline is left out of this cup design, but visually the spacing looks the same.

[image: Park Tool BBT-22]

Comment: After you eventually get the BB removed, you should add the manufacturer / model information into the question, as that could help others in the future asking about a similar BB.

Comment: @dlatikay I was also initially fooled by the lighting in the original photo. They are fused slots, not fused teeth. The extra teeth will fit the wider slot just fine.

Comment: upvoted (and deleted embarrassing comment :-))

Comment: @renesis Thanks for the answer, I have just orderered a BBT-22 tool. I will update the answer once I get the tool. and I manage to figure out manifacturer/ model of the BB out.

Comment: The tool was correct. The BB is actually seized to the frame, so I will have to bring it to the LBS, but that's another story...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a 20 spline lockring where pairs of slots at 12, 3, 6 and 9 o'clock are joined together.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to renesis's answer.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino Could be both answers were posted close together and neither saw the other's answer.

Comment: @Criggie There's 25 minutes between them.